# C# HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse blocks in one class but not another

Tags: c#

I am validating a list of proxies using HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse.  It works really well, I can validate thousands of proxies in seconds and doesn't block.

In another class within my project, I am calling the same code and it blocks.

**Proxy validation method (Doesn't block):**

```
public void BeginTest(IProxyTest test, Action<ProxyStatus> callback, int timeout = 10000)
{
    var req = HttpWebRequest.Create(test.URL);
    req.Proxy = new WebProxy(this.ToString());
    req.Timeout = timeout;

    WebHelper.BeginGetResponse(req, new Action<RequestCallbackState>(callbackState =>
    {
        if (callbackState.Exception != null)
        {
            callback(ProxyStatus.Invalid);
        }
        else
        {
            var responseStream = callbackState.ResponseStream;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (responseString.Contains(test.Validation))
                {
                    callback(ProxyStatus.Valid);
                }
                else
                {
                    callback(ProxyStatus.Invalid);
                }
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

**WebHelper.BeginGetResponse**

```
public static void BeginGetResponse(WebRequest request, Action<RequestCallbackState> responseCallback)
{
    Task<WebResponse> asyncTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);
    ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject((asyncTask as IAsyncResult).AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(TimeoutCallback), request, request.Timeout, true);
    asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        WebResponse response = task.Result;
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        responseCallback(new RequestCallbackState(responseStream));
        responseStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);
    //Handle errors
    asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        var exception = task.Exception;
        responseCallback(new RequestCallbackState(exception.InnerException));
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

**Other class with a similar method that also calls WebHelper.BeginGetResponse, but blocks (why?)**

```
public void BeginTest(Action<ProxyStatus> callback, int timeout = 10000)
{
    var req = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
    req.Timeout = timeout;

    WebHelper.BeginGetResponse(req, new Action<RequestCallbackState>(callbackState =>
    {
        if (callbackState.Exception != null)
        {
            callback(ProxyStatus.Invalid);
        }
        else
        {
            var responseStream = callbackState.ResponseStream;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (responseString.Contains(Validation))
                {
                    callback(ProxyStatus.Valid);
                }
                else
                {
                    callback(ProxyStatus.Invalid);
                }
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

**Calling code which blocks**

```
private async void validateTestsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (var test in tests)
        {
            test.BeginTest((status) => test.Status = status);
        }
    });
}
```

**Calling code which doesn't block:**

```
public static async Task BeginTests(ICollection<Proxy> proxies, ICollection<ProxyJudge> judges, int timeout = 10000, IProgress<int> progress = null)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (var proxy in proxies)
        {
            proxy.BeginTest(judges.GetRandomItem(), new Action<ProxyStatus>(status =>
            {
                proxy.Status = status;
            }), timeout);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What line blocks if you dont mind me asking?

Comment: @TheGeneral Hi, I edited my question and added the calling code which blocks after about 10 iterations.

Comment: When you say blocking, does it ever come back, or is it deadlocked foreve4r

Comment: @TheGeneral Seems to deadlock forever really.  About 10 iterations complete, then it blocks forever and the rest of my for loop never finishes.  No exceptions so it's make it hard to figure out whats going on, even stranger that one implementation works fine and the other does this.

Comment: @TheGeneral So I added a proxy to the request that was blocking, and now it works as intended.  I've narrowed it down that not setting the Proxy property on the HttpWebRequest being passed into WebHelper.BeginGetResponse is the root cause, now I just need to figure out a solution.  It must be checking my system proxy settings when I don't set that property, which I'm guessing is why I'm getting the unexpected blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Although this dosnt address your problem exactly, it might help you out a little

Here are a couple of problems

1. You are using APM ([Asynchronous Programming Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm))
2. You are using the `ThreadPool` class which seems a little old fashioned
3. You are doing *IO bound* work and blocking threads on the threadpool
4. You are using a weird mix of APM and TBA asynchronous models
5. And seemingly tying up your thread pool waiting for IO

So you are doing *IO bound* work, the best pattern to use as you might have guess is the TBA `async` `await` pattern. basically every time you wait for a an *IO Completion* port you want to give that thread back to the operating system and be nice to your system inturn freeing up resources for where its needed.

Also you obviously want some degree of parallelism and you are best to at least have some control over it.

I would suggest this is a nice job for *TPL Dataflow* and an *ActionBlock*

**Given**

```
public class Proxy
{
   public ProxyStatus ProxyStatus { get; set; }
   public string ProxyUrl { get; set; }
   public string WebbUrl { get; set; }
   public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

**ActionBlock Example**

```
public static async Task DoWorkLoads(List<Proxy> results)
{
   var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                     {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50
                     };

   var block = new ActionBlock<Proxy>(CheckUrlAsync, options);

   foreach (var proxy in results)
   {
      block.Post(proxy);
   }

   block.Complete();
   await block.Completion;
}
```

**CheckUrlAsync Example**

```
// note i havent tested this, add pepper and salt to taste
public static async Task CheckUrlAsync(Proxy proxy)
{
   try
   {

      var request = WebRequest.Create(proxy.Url);

      if (proxy.ProxyUrl != null)
         request.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy.ProxyUrl);

      using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
      {
         using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
         {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
               var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
               if (responseString.Contains("asdasd"))
                  proxy.ProxyStatus = ProxyStatus.Valid;
               else
                  proxy.ProxyStatus = ProxyStatus.Invalid;
            }
         }
      }

   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      proxy.ProxyStatus = ProxyStatus.Error;
      proxy.Error = e.Message;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
 await DoWorkLoads(proxies to test);
```

**Summary**

The code is neater, you arnt throwing actions all over the place, you using `async` and `await` you have ditched APM, you have control of the degrees of parallel and you are being nice to the thread pool

Comment: Hi TheGeneral, I had tried using DataFlow ActionBlock/GetResponseAsync, and it worked but my throughput was much higher using BeginGetResponse (I can test a list of 2k proxies in 10 seconds with a 10 second timeout, with ActionBlock I could test that 2k list in maybe 1-2 minutes), which is why I am using it in this case, because I am validating large lists of proxies.

Comment: @DavidStampher Yeah that kind of surprises me a little, i might test it out myself, either way i dont thinks its your problem, and the answer was just a diffrent approach if you didnt know about it . however ill remove this soon as its not really an answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by wrapping the code in the BeginTest method which was blocking mysteriously in an Action, and then calling BeginInvoke on that Action.

I deduced this was caused by not setting the Proxy property on the HttpWebRequest in that method, which seemed to be causing a synchronous lookup of my systems proxy.

```
public void BeginTest(Action<ProxyStatus> callback, int timeout = 10000)
{
    var action = new Action(() =>
    {
        var req = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
        req.Timeout = timeout;

        WebHelper.BeginGetResponse(req, new Action<RequestCallbackState>(callbackState =>
        {
            if (callbackState.Exception != null)
            {
                callback(ProxyStatus.Invalid);
            }
            else
            {
                var responseStream = callbackState.ResponseStream;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    if (responseString.Contains(Validation))
                    {
                        callback(ProxyStatus.Valid);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        callback(ProxyStatus.Invalid);
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    });

    action.BeginInvoke(null, null);
}
```